# Is there a way to do this in a simple query?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery

I have a BIG (23 millions rows) table CONTRATOS which has these columns:

```
SELECT
    CONTRATO,
    CODIGO_ORIGEN,
    ORIGEN
FROM CONTRATOS;
```

There are multiple rows with the same value for the column CODIGO_ORIGEN:

```
CODIGO_ORIGEN     CONTRATO       ORIGEN 
-------------    ----------     --------
     1               345          CONT
     1               363          BKP
     1               645          BKP
     1               365          CONT
```

I need to get only one CONTRATO per CODIGO_ORIGEN but always prioritizing the **'CONT'** value. So in this sample it would be the CONTRATO with value **365**

I was trying to to something like this:

```
SELECT  
   CODIGO_ORIGEN,
   CASE
    WHEN ORIGEN = 'CONT' THEN
        FIRST_VALUE (CONTRATO) OVER (PARTITION BY CODIGO_ORIGEN ORDER BY CONTRATO DESC) 
    WHEN ORIGEN = 'BKP' THEN
        FIRST_VALUE (CONTRATO) OVER (PARTITION BY CODIGO_ORIGEN ORDER BY CAMPO1 DESC, CAMPO2 DESC, CONTRATO DESC) 
   END AS CONTRATO
FROM CONTRATOS;
```

In case ORIGEN is 'CONTR' i should sort by the highest CONTRATO and get the CONTRATO column.
In case ORIGEN is 'BKP' i should sort by different columns and get the CONTRATO column.

Finally, i should be able to have one unique row with CODIGO_ORIGEN -> CONTRATO (1:1).

Is there a simple way to do this (1 query)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Adding just one sample table of data could replace all the text, and you should do that.

Comment: I added 2 simple queries to clarify the case. Do you understand the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Edit the question and add sample data as asked by @TimBiegeleisen. So that chances of getting good answer will be increased. Anyway, answer to your question (asked in comment), NO

Comment: Hi guys, i edited my question, i hope you can understand now. Thanks!

Comment: Your needs are still poorly defined. First off you show only 1 value for codigo_origen (a poor data universe) and intricate to prioritize origen ->  cont. Does that mean if origen ->  cont then exclude origen -> bkp. from the result. Further your data is incomplete, missing columns campo1 and, campo2, which you use in the query. Finally, you request "unique row with codigo_origen -> contrato (1:1)" What does that mean? There seems to be nothing in the data to produce that (1:1) result.

Comment: I mean i need only one row for each CODIGO_ORIGEN and when there are 2 differents values for the column ORIGEN (CONT, BKP) i should get the CONT one.

The CAMPO1 and CAMPO2 are columns of the table too but that is not the point at all. Its just the way i need to do the sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in order to rank your rows per `codigo_origen`. Here is one way to write its `ORDER BY` clause. There are others, too.

```
select *
from
(
  select  
     c.*,
     row_number() over (
       partition by codigo_origen 
       order by 
         case when origen 'BKP' then campo1 end desc,
         case when origen 'BKP' then campo2 end desc,
         origen desc
     ) as rn
  from contratos c
) ranked
where rn = 1
order by codigo_origen;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it:

```
      SELECT 
        C.contrato, C.codigo_origen,  NVL2(MX.CONTRATO, NULL, 'F') AS ESTADO, NVL2(MX.CONTRATO, NULL, '4008') AS ERROR
      FROM MGR_CUENTA_CTL C
      LEFT JOIN
      (
          select /*+ PARALLEL */
            DISTINCT CODIGO_ORIGEN,
            CASE
              WHEN ORIGEN_TABLA = 'CONT' THEN FIRST_VALUE(CONTRATO) OVER (PARTITION BY CODIGO_ORIGEN ORDER BY CONTRATO DESC) 
              WHEN ORIGEN_TABLA = 'BKP' THEN FIRST_VALUE(CONTRATO) OVER (PARTITION BY CODIGO_ORIGEN ORDER BY CAMPO1 DESC, CAMPO2 DESC) 
            END AS CONTRATO
          FROM
          (  
             SELECT /*+ PARALLEL */ ctl.*
             FROM mgr_cuenta_ctl ctl
             LEFT JOIN 
             (
                   select /*+ PARALLEL */ CODIGO_ORIGEN
                   from mgr_cuenta_ctl
                   group by codigo_origen having count(distinct origen) > 1
             ) CTL2 ON ctl.CODIGO_ORIGEN = ctl2.CODIGO_ORIGEN
             WHERE (CTL2.CODIGO_ORIGEN IS NOT NULL AND CTL.ORIGEN <> 'BKP') OR (CTL2.CODIGO_ORIGEN IS NULL)
          )
      ) MX ON MX.CONTRATO = C.CONTRATO;
```

I think it does what i was trying to explain.

Does it has sense for you?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is `origen = 'CONT'`, use analytic `count()`. If yes - use analytic function with first ordering method, if no - second ordering:

```
select mgr_cuenta_ctl.*,
       case 
       when count(case origen when 'CONT' then 1 end) over (partition by codigo_origen) > 0
       then first_value(contrato) over (
            partition by codigo_origen
            order by case origen when 'CONT' then 1 end, contrato desc)
       else first_value(contrato) over (
            partition by codigo_origen
            order by case origen when 'BKP' then 1 end, campo1 desc, campo2 desc, contrato desc)
       end as best
  from mgr_cuenta_ctl
```

If you want only grouped values, without details, remove `partition by` clauses:

```
select codigo_origen,
       case when count(case origen when 'CONT' then 1 end) > 0
       then max(contrato) keep (dense_rank first 
                order by case origen when 'CONT' then 1 end, contrato desc) 
       else max(contrato) keep (dense_rank first 
                order by case origen when 'BKP' then 1 end, campo1 desc, campo2 desc) 
       end as best
  from mgr_cuenta_ctl
  group by codigo_origen
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bede85e45f992dc192eee17ab3b9445a)</sup>**

BTW. I tried to analyse your query, but it throwed some strange errors and I gave up. Here you touch table only once, no self-joins, so it should be faster.

Comment: Thanks for asking! Is it doing the same thing that the latest query i posted?